# How to identify binary data in MySql Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design, md5

I have a database that stores the location of some data. For simplicity, lets make it

```
Resource
----------
id (PK)
resourceLocation
```

In my application, which is written in Java, it has come to a point where all I have is the binary data of the file that is stored at `resourceLocation`. With just this binary data, I need some way to be able to get this record from the database.

The only thing I can think of is something like this. Add a new column to the `Resource` table called md5. This will store the MD5 of the file located at resourceLocation.

```
Resource
----------
id (PK)
resourceLocation
md5
```

Then in my code, when all I have is the binary data, I can simply get the MD5 of the data and be able to find the record in the database.

I had a couple of questions about this approach. First, can anyone think of a better way to do it. Second, is there a better hash algorithm than MD5 for this purpose. My concern is that I may wind up with 2 files creating the same MD5 hash. If that happens, my approach fails.

Comment: Your approach sounds good, assuming that you genuinely can't get the `resourceLocation` from within Java. Why is that? How did you come upon the file contents without the file's path?  Or are you trying to see if a received file matches one already in the database?  Probability of two files having colliding MD5 hashes should be 1 in 2^128 (approximately 340 trillion trillion trillion), although if this is for a security application one can create deliberately colliding files.  Other hashing algorithms (e.g. SHA-1) are more secure, but I should think MD5 is *more* than enough for this purpose.

Comment: @eggyal,+1, wondering same here as how he'll come about the file without starting with the file location. Hashes are all well and good but to be somewhat absolutely sure, also *salt* your hash values if security is a huge concern. Another thing you'll have to consider eventually is the efficiency of your back-to-front approach for large files during hashing as hashing calculations degrade with payload size and system resources.You *will* have to decide between a faster or more efficient hashing algorithm eventually. Cheers